# Would it be acceptable to ask for an Intern position until a full-time position becomes available?

Tags: software-industry, recruitment

I passed the hiring committee in my dream company back in November 2019.

The recruiter told me *even before passing* the committee, that, since I am a new graduate, and there are currently no open positions in my country (a small country with just two offices), she doesn't have a job for me at the moment.

After passing, she told me that she can check a re-location option somewhere else in Europe if I am willing to do so. I declined and told her I am willing to wait until a position opens up (which is even better for me, since technically I finished my degree but I wanted to take my courses; which I can do in a discount if I am still registered as a student).

Lately, the company puts up that it is recruiting for its internship programs. Would it be acceptable for me to message the recruiter telling her that I am interested in an internship program until a position opens up?

Comment: If you are eligible for the internship program, I would certainly let the recruiter know. Though they probably can't guarantee that you will pivot straight into a full time role at completion.

Answer (score 1):

> would it be acceptable for me to message the recruiter telling her that I am interested in an internship programs until a position opens up?

Yes, certainly. An internship is often a good first step to get a foot in the door. You should make sure you understand the conditions:

1. Is it paid or unpaid, what type of benefits or support will you get?
2. Is there a time limit? What's the trigger point for ending the internship?
3. Is this in the same work area/department, you want a permanent job in?
4. Is there a credible path for converting an internship to a permanent position? If yes, what are the rules/guidelines?
5. How is this all impacted by the current pandemic and upcoming recession?

Once you have all the info, you can decide if that's a reasonable choice for you or not. This also depends of course on what other options you may have, but these are not good times for job hunting.

Answer (score 0):

> Would it be acceptable for me to message the recruiter telling her that I am interested in an internship program until a position opens up?

There's nothing stopping you from talking this through with the recruiter. There's no harm in asking them. They has access to the right people who can actually take a decision on this matter.

Since the committee has already approved you, and have even promised you a job when a position becomes available, the decision makers would be more willing to take you as an intern.

However, you may also wish to evaluate (possibly by discussing with a hiring manager) on if and how the internship could potentially benefit your actual full-time role.

Answer (score 0):

> Would it be acceptable for me to message the recruiter telling her
>   that I am interested in an internship program until a position opens
>   up?

It's perfectly reasonable to ask.

You may or may not fit what they are looking for in an intern. And this internship may or may not lead to a full-time position.

But it never hurts to ask.